# Which type of database does Parse use? (SQL or NoSQL)?

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am new in parse.com i don't know parse use which database link SQL or NoSQL.

I use parse for android application. I am appraising to move to Parse platform but I am not sure how Database Structure parse use And for the Android App which framework do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo DB.
[Similar question here](https://www.parse.com/questions/which-type-of-database-does-parse-use-sql-or-nosql)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.parse.com/questions/which-type-of-database-does-parse-use-sql-or-nosql
This website has your answer. It seems mongoDB is used by Parse.